# Drag and drop quiz in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been creating this drag and drop. It works well and fine and good. First, I move from Scene 1 of the quiz to the Scene 2, it works fine. But, when I move from Scene 2 to the Scene 3 of the quiz, the previous answer from Scene 2 follows and remain on the same spot it'd been dragged before.

Can someone help me to solve this? Please. I need to present this tomorrow:(

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var hitArrayClass:Array = new Array(answerTargetQ4, answerTargetQ41, answerTargetQ42, answerTargetQ43, answerTargetQ5, answerTargetQ51, answerTargetQ52, answerTargetQ53, answerTargetQ6, answerTargetQ61, answerTargetQ62, answerTargetQ63, answerTargetQ7, answerTargetQ71, answerTargetQ72,answerTargetQ73);
var dropArrayClass: Array = new Array(answerQ4, answerQ41, answerQ42, answerQ43, answerQ5, answerQ51, answerQ52, answerQ53, answerQ6, answerQ61, answerQ62, answerQ63, answerQ7, answerQ71, answerQ72, answerQ73);
var positionsArrayClass: Array = new Array();


for (var a:int = 0; a < dropArrayClass.length; a++) {
    dropArrayClass[a].buttonMode = true;
    dropArrayClass[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveDown);
    dropArrayClass[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

    positionsArrayClass.push({xPos:dropArrayClass[a].x, yPos:dropArrayClass[a].y});

}


function moveDown (e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();

    setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);

    if (e.currentTarget !=null){
        //e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    }
}


function mUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var dropIndex:int = dropArrayClass.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    target.stopDrag();

    if (target.hitTestObject(hitArrayClass[dropIndex])){    
target.x = hitArrayClass[dropIndex].x;
target.y = hitArrayClass[dropIndex].y;

    target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveDown);
    target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);



} else {
       target.x = positionsArrayClass[dropIndex].xPos;
       target.y = positionsArrayClass[dropIndex].yPos;
   }


  }
```

Comment: Where is the code you've posted?  Scene 2?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis this is the code that I used for Scene2. The code is the same for all scenes. I just changed some important variables and so on.

Comment: how do you move to a new scene? I don't see anything in your code for that

Comment: if you comment out this line, does it work?  `setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);`

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Hi. Thank you for your help. It works out! I really appreciate your help ;)

Comment: When you manipulate a timeline display object's display list attribute (addChild/setChildIndex) via code, it will no longer react to timeline keyframes, and will need to be explicitly removed from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `setChildIndex` (or addChild) on a display object that originates on the timeline, it is then controlled though code and not the timeline.

You either need to not use `setChildIndex`,  or explicitly remove item through code when your scene changes:

```
function rightBeforeSceneChange():void {
    //iterate over all your items
    for(i:int=0;i<dropArrayClass.length;i++){
        //if they have a parent (eg are on the display) remove them from it
        if(dropArrayClass[i].parent){
            dropArrayClass[i].parent.removeChild(dropArrayClass[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. Now i can solve my problem. I reallly appreciate your help! :)